# Do not resubmit forms in Django wizard end

Tags: django, forms, django-formwizard

I have wizard implemented with `SessionWizardView` and I am doing some backend validation and other method calls on every step (e.g. inside form `init`, `clean` methods or inside `process_step`). So actually I do not need to submit all forms and save data from all steps at the end of my wizard. I just need to be redirected to main page after last step. What is best way to do that? Override something like `render_done()`? Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not just implement `done(self, form_list, **kwargs)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like overriding render_done() method works great. But my problem was all about validation. I had field where validator was checking if user exists. If it does not - he was created on that step. So revalidation will alway fail here :). Remvoing this code:

```
if not form_obj.is_valid():
    return self.render_revalidation_failure(form_key, form_obj, **kwargs)
```

solved revalidation issue at the wizard end.